# Scala Worksheet Extension Methods error: not found value extension

Tags: scala, extension-methods

I'm working on a Scala Worksheet file using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) Visual Studio Code extension.

Everything works fine until I had to implement the Extension Method, the editor raises the error "not found: value extension" highlighting as shown in the image:
[image: example]

Following my scala version:

```
scala> util.Properties.versionNumberString
res0: String = 2.11.12
```

how can i bypass this problem?

Comment: `extension` is a Scala-3 keyword. It won't work in earlier Scala releases. You'll have to use an `implicit` class to get the same effect.

Comment: Namely, `implicit class MyExtension(c: Circle) { def circumference: Double = c.radius * math.Pi * 2 }`.